# XML Connectionstrings

Tags: database, vb.net, string, connection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Citrus_Welding.My.MySettings.CitWeldConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Citrus           Welding\CitWeld.mdb&quot;"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

I am looking at the connection string, I need the Data Source to = a selected file from another page by default... I tried & pagename.openfiledialog.filename & but I keep getting an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're saying that you want the user to be able to set the `Data Source` at run time.  If so then omit it from the connection string in the config file and set it like this at run time:

```
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(My.Settings.CitWeldConnectionString)

builder.DataSource = newDataSourceValue

Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you! :)